# How to highlight multiple rows selected using CTRL+ mouse click in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a table with one column. The table has to support both single row selection and multiple row selection and I want to highlight selected rows.

I selected multiple rows using CTRL+ mosue click.

In .html file,

```html
     <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table" >
            <tbody>

              <tr class="record" *ngFor="let item of staticData; let i = index" (click)="selectName( $event, item,i)" 
              [class.active]="i== selectedRow">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

In .ts file,

```js
    public selectName(event: any,item: any, i: number) {
    
    console.log(item);
    this.selectedRow= i;
    if(!event.ctrlKey)
    {
      this.singleName= item.name;
      console.log(this.singleName);
      this.nameArray=[];
     
    }
    else
    {
       this.addToArray(this.nameArray, item);
    }
    }
```

I am able to highlight one row using the above code. How to highlight multiple rows selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping a separate array I suggest using a property on each partner:

```
<tr class="record" *ngFor="let item of staticData; let i = index" (click)="selectPartner( $event, item,i)" 
          [class.active]="item.isSelected">
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>

public selectPartner(event: any,item: any, i: number) {

    // Set a bool where you listen for ctrl key down so you can check against it here
    if (isCtrlKeyDown) {
      item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
    }
    else {
      staticData.forEach((partner) => partner.isSelected = false);
      item.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```

To then get all selected partners just do a filter:

```
var selectedPartners = staticData.filter((partner) => partner.isSelected);
```